# Monitor connected to a surge protector goes blank for a few seconds everytime room lights are switched on

Tags: display, power-supply, power, surge-protection

I have noticed this problem in 2 separate locations. In both cases they are computer monitors connected to a surge protector extension cord.

Every time the lights or fans are switched on or the fridge door is opened, the monitor goes blank for a few seconds.

Both extension cords with surge protection are of different brands. Monitors in both instances are of different brands.

I have a computer that is in another room and not connected through a surge protector that **does not have this issue**.

Does anyone has an idea why this happens and what can be done to remedy this?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that mains power is simply weak, possibly under spec at your location(s). To measure the transients/brownout will take some (oscilloscope-level) equipment. Probably the only consumer-level fix is to run these monitors of a good UPS.

Also, have you tried running the monitors straigh from the wall, sans the extension cords? MOVs inside surge protectors fail after a while.